# Incorrect behavior with Set-Variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'd like to set a counted value (number of XML files in a folder) to a variable.

```
Set-variable (Get-ChildItem $filepath|where{$_.Extension -eq ".xls"}|Measure-Object).Count -Value $NumberOfCabinets
```

After this, my variable named `NumberOfCabinets` gives me a value of 0 every time.

How should the command be changed to store the correct value in the variable?

Comment: do you want to set the NumberOfCabinets Variable or what do you want to do? I guess your Value should be the code and the name is NumberOfCabinets which would be like : `Set-variable -name NumberOfCabinets -value (Get-ChildItem $filepath|where{$_.Extension -eq ".xls"}|Measure-Object).Count` but I would just do `$NumberOfCabinets = (Get-ChildItem $filepath|where{$_.Extension -eq ".xls"}|Measure-Object).Count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by SimonS in the comments, you need to switch which expression is the `-Name` and which is the `-Value`. Currently, your expression to get the number of XLS files is implicitly the `-Name` parameter to `Set-Variable` — i.e. the name of the variable to set — and the contents of `$NumberOfCabinets` is the data for that variable. Since `$NumberOfCabinets` has not been set yet, the new variable is assigned null. For example, if there were five XLS files, a variable named `$5` would be created and set to null because your count expression provides the variable name.

Usually, `Set-Variable` is only necessary if you need to dynamically choose which variable to set. If you want to use it anyway, your command would be like this:

```
Set-Variable 'NumberOfCabinets' (Get-ChildItem $filepath | where {$_.Extension -eq ".xls"} | Measure-Object).Count
```

Note that the name of the variable to be set/created is just passed as a string.

However, it's probably simpler to just set the variable using the standard assignment operator:

```
$NumberOfCabinets = (Get-ChildItem $filepath | where {$_.Extension -eq ".xls"} | Measure-Object).Count
```

Using some aliases and the fact that PowerShell collections already have a `Count` property, we can even condense it a bit:

```
$NumberOfCabinets = (gci $filepath | ? { $_.Extension -eq '.xls' }).Count
```